# Cypress - Test belong to relationship case

Tags: laravel, relationship, cypress

Is it possible to use cypress for testing relationship between models?

For example, I have this kind of relationship: a teacher has many students, each student belongs to a teacher. After the teacher A logged in, at url "/my-students", he or she will see a list of all his or her students.

What I want to test is to make sure none of the students listed on "/my-students" page belong to teacher B than teacher A.

Can I test this case with cypress? Is it possible and how to do it if it's possible?

Comment: Have you tried having a list of expected students and just checking if the displayed students match the list?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "yes" you can absolutely do this kind of testing. There are dozens of ways, but I'm going to suggest what I consider to be the simplest approach.

1. Make sure the data being used by your website doesn't change. You want your tests to be deterministic... none of this *run a database query to determine the expected results* stuff.
2. The first time through, verify the page contents manually
3. Use `cy.snapshot()` to record the current page state for future comparison. This is an additional npm package from Gleb Bahmutov (a Cypress developer). Full instructions, including installation, can be found [here](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2018/01/16/end-to-end-snapshot-testing/).

Your hypothetical test would look something like this:

```
describe('student directory page', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // Log in
    cy.logIn('lizstewart@example.com') // This is usually a custom command; up to you
  })

  it('displays the correct students', () => {
    // Go to the page
    cy.visit('my-students')

    // Check for the correct students
    cy.get('#studentList').snapshot()
  })
})
```

The first time the test runs it will pass no matter what, and will write out a file titled `snapshots.js`, which you can commit to your repo. All subsequent test runs will fail if the HTML output doesn't match the previous content exactly.

It's a blunt approach, but it's quick and effective.